# Is there an easy way to "reload" an object's methods without re-instantiating it entirely?

Tags: python, oop

This is typical pattern that I run into in Python but probably applies to most other multi-paradigm languages.

I write a bunch of functions. Some of these are like load_data() and some are like do_something_with_data(). That is the latter acts on the data that is read in with the first function. Let's say it takes 1 minute to read in the data.

After a while I refactor the code so that these are both methods within a class. While this seems neater, it is also harder to develop on. That is, if I fix a bug in do_something_with_data() the object that is already instantiated is not fixed. I have to re-instantiate it which might take a minute or so since it has to read the data.

```
object=my_object();object.load_data();object.do_something_with_data()
```

I am wondering if there is a good pattern for handling this issue. Can you update an object's methods without refreshing the data? Should I write a method that takes an old object and copies in all the data fields from an object that has been saved? Other ideas?

Comment: How are you reloading your code?

Comment: reload(my_module) and then my_module.my_object() etc

Comment: As a general rule if there is something heavy that is shared between instances, use a [this pattern](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531/) so you don't have to generate it repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods are looked up on the *class*. On module reload, existing instances end up referencing a class that no longer exists; their `__class__` points to an object that was the old `module.classname`, and is not the same object as the new `module.classname`.

You have two options:

1. Update the old class to have your new method:

   ```
   existing_instance.__class__.methodname = module.classname.methodname.__func__
   ```
2. Replace the class references on the existing objects:

   ```
   existing_instance.__class__ = module.classname
   ```

Comment: Thanks. That second one is one I can remember. Tested and seems to work as you say.

Comment: Is there a way to may a reload method on the object that would reload the module and update it's own class? Maybe that is circular.

Comment: Not without custom code that does exactly what I posted in my answer. :-)

Comment: I don't think that will work as a method. That is you can't just do object.reload() instead of typing those two lines into the terminal, right? In R you can execute in the parent scope but I don't think you can in Python.

Comment: @Dave31415: I meant that you could write a `reload` function yourself that looked up the module to reload (`sys.modules[self.__module__]`), reloaded that module, found the class (from `self.__class__.__name__`)  then replaced `self.__class__` with the new version.